# Store value of Combo Box between runs

Tags: java, swing, preferences

In want to store the value of this combo box so that the user doesn't have to make a selection each time. I am trying to do it with preferences but the value is not getting store. I keep getting the very first selection made returned.

The pref PREF_AREA seem to be getting update correctly when a value is changed just not stored between runs.

Here is my attempt.

```
    public void myInitComponents() {
    // Set default value from prefs for Directory
    Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(JFrameTest.class);

    // Set default value for AREA
    final String PREF_AREA = "Select AREA";
    comboAREA.setSelectedItem(prefs.get(PREF_AREA, ""));
    // Set AREA Options
    comboAREA.addItem("San Deigo");
    comboAREA.addItem("Los Angeles");
    comboAREA.addItem("San Francisco");

    }


private void comboAREAActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(JFrameTest.class);
    final String PREF_AREA = "Select AREA";
    prefs.put(PREF_AREA, comboAREA.getSelectedItem().toString());
    comboAREA.setSelectedItem(PREF_AREA);
    System.out.println(comboAREA.getSelectedItem().toString());
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have also tried this but it still is stuck on the first value I ever chose from the combo. It seems not to be storing the value of combo when a change is made.

```
  public void myInitComponents() {
    // Set default value from prefs for Directory
    Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(JFrameTest.class);

    // Set default value for AREA
    final String PREF_AREA = "Select AREA";
    // Set AREA Options
    comboAREA.addItem("San Deigo");
    comboAREA.addItem("Los Angeles");
    comboAREA.addItem("San Francisco");
    comboAREA.setSelectedItem(prefs.get(PREF_AREA, ""));
    }


private void comboAREAActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Preferences prefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(JFrameTest.class);
    final String PREF_AREA = "Select AREA";
    prefs.put(PREF_AREA, comboAREA.getSelectedItem().toString());
    System.out.println(comboAREA.getSelectedItem().toString());
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Yes. If I breakpoint it, I hit the breakpoint everytime I select it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move the line      `comboAREA.setSelectedItem(prefs.get(PREF_AREA, ""));`

after you add items to comboBox in your `myInitComponents` method

```
comboAREA.addItem("San Deigo");
comboAREA.addItem("Los Angeles");
comboAREA.addItem("San Francisco");
comboAREA.setSelectedItem(prefs.get(PREF_AREA, ""))
```

You are also setting your key value as selected item in your `comboAREAActionPerformed` method
`comboAREA.setSelectedItem(PREF_AREA); // this is unnecessary`

Answer (score 0):

It was to do with the way JFormDesigner setup the order of events.

The Action Listener is added in the init() method *before* setSelectedItem and before adding items.

The first item to the combo box triggers the action listener, meaning it then save the first item as the previous selected one.